# Can not find symbol when using assertThatThrownBy with a lambda which has unchecked assignment

Tags: java, assertj

I'm using JUnit and AssertJ to test my code, and here is the test:

```
public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        Foo f = new Foo();
        assertThatThrownBy(() -> f.abc(Collections.EMPTY_MAP)).isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class)
                .hasMessageContaining("test");
    }
}
```

the code of Foo is as follow:

```
public class Foo {
    public void abc(Map<Integer, String> ss){
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }
}
```

When I compile above code, a error is thrown, which says javac can't found symbol `hasMessageContaining` in AbstractAssert, but if I change `Collections.EMPTY_MAP` to `new HashMap()`, everything works fine.

It seems that `isInstanceOf` returns `AbstractAssert` rather than `AbstractThrowableAssert`.

And, if I change lambda to anonymous class, above error vanished either.

So, where is the problem of my code?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that EMPTY_MAP is a raw type (Map), if you use [`emptyMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyMap--) it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, I found that too, but can you tell me why unchecked assignment in lambda can affect outside method?

Comment: why does it matter, if it is a raw type or not?